# Doxygen and Xcode 4 -  Xcode does not see the doc set

Tags: xcode4, doxygen

I've built the Docset for my code, and I'm trying to get Xcode to compile the Docset when I perform a build.  However, Xcode doesn't see the docset once it builds (The DocSet is visible in the directory).

Here's my process:

1) Generate the doxygen output

```
 doxygen doxygen.config
```

2) go into the html directory and generate the docset

```
 make

[...]

14: MyCodeIOSDecoder_8h.html
15: MyCodeIOSHighLevel_8h.html
Loading symbols from [...]/source/html/org.doxygen.Project.docset/Contents/Resources/Tokens.xml
*     93 tokens processed (   0.0 sec)

Linking up related token references
Sorting tokens
```

3) installing doc set

```
make install

[...]
cp -R org.doxygen.Project.docset ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets
```

4) no docset in xcode 4, maybe old doxygen version Doxygen version 1.7.4-20110629

double check where the docset should appear in Xcode 4

Am I missing something?

Comment: I guess it was in the title.  How to get DOXYGEN Xcode Doc set to appear / user in XCODE 4?

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume Doxygen output folder is ~/Documents/myDocSet. 
Inside, there's the folder html.

1. Make sure the doxyfile includes

   > ```
   > GENERATE_DOCSET        = YES
   > ```
2. Open the terminal

   > ```
   > cd ~/Documents/myDocSet/html
   > make install
   > ```
3. Launch the Applescript loadDocSet.scpt

   > ```
   > tell application "Xcode"
   > load documentation set with path
   >         "~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/myDocSet.docset"
   > end tell
   > ```